# Nested data in Parquet with Python

Tags: python, json, parquet, dask

I have a file that has one JSON per line. Here is a sample:

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": "abcdef",
        "price": 19.99,
        "specs": {
            "voltage": "110v",
            "color": "white"
        }
    },
    "user": "Daniel Severo"
}
```

I want to create a parquet file with columns such as:

```
product.id, product.price, product.specs.voltage, product.specs.color, user
```

I know that parquet has a nested encoding using the Dremel algorithm, but I haven't been able to use it in python (not sure why).

I'm a heavy pandas and dask user, so the pipeline I'm trying to construct is `json data -> dask -> parquet -> pandas`, although **if anyone has a simple example of creating and reading these nested encodings in parquet using Python** I think that would be good enough :D

**EDIT**

So, after digging in the PRs I found this: https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/pull/177

which is basically what I want to do. Although, I still can't make it work all the way through. How exactly do I tell dask/fastparquet that my `product` column is nested?

- [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) version: 0.15.1
- [fastparquet](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/) version: 0.1.1

Comment: fastparquet can probably *read* a parquet file structured as above, but not of writing them. This is because a pandas dataframe (the target structure) would rarely look like that. You could flatten the schema yourself to a pandas dataframe, and any repeated values (lists, dicts) you could encode using JSON (object_encoding={'specs': 'JSON'}) on write.

Comment: (NB: writing of MAP and LIST parquet types is doable for fastparquet, but seemed to me like more effort than demand can justify)

Comment: Did something like that. I'll post an example as an answer here soon. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielSevero Out of curiosity, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Implementing the conversions on both the read and write path for arbitrary Parquet nested data is quite complicated to get right -- implementing the shredding and reassembly algorithm with associated conversions to some Python data structures. We have this on the roadmap in Arrow / parquet-cpp (see https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp/tree/master/src/parquet/arrow), but it has not been completed yet (only support for simple structs and lists/arrays are supported now). It is important to have this functionality because other systems that use Parquet, like Impala, Hive, Presto, Drill, and Spark, have native support for nested types in their SQL dialects, so we need to be able to read and write these structures faithfully from Python.

This can be analogously implemented in fastparquet as well, but it's going to be a lot of work (and test cases to write) no matter how you slice it.

I will likely take on the work (in parquet-cpp) personally later this year if no one beats me to it, but I would love to have some help.

Comment: Awesome! I found a workaround for now (probably not the smartest way). I'm gonna create a .ipynb with a working example of my solution. I'm sure more people have this issue. Do you have any examples of how to use the current nested functionalities with `pyarrow`?

Comment: @wes-mckinney : if someone wanted to write a structures parquet data-set like this, then what do you suppose the input data looks like? Can arrow handle such nested things, or are we talking python objects (dicts)?

Comment: Arrow has native lists (arrays), structs, maps, etc., so you could convert to Arrow nested data before writing (we'll need some functions to simplify converting between built-in Python data structures and Arrow data)

Comment: @DanielSevero there is limited support for reading lists and structs (e.g. Arrow structs back to Python dicts was implemented here https://github.com/apache/arrow/commit/e268ce87e5d8f93ff6ecc871d218a58605b9692f) -- I don't think the write path is complete. Someone will need to spend a few days implementing complete nested data support and adding documentation.

Comment: @WesMcKinney Anything new on this, Wes? Thanks

Comment: Still waiting on some development help with this. I expect it to be completed this year (i.e. in 2018) but not sure when

Comment: @WesMcKinney Is this still on the project roadmap? Thx very much

Comment: @WesMcKinney Was this ever completed?

Comment: According to the links below this was not implemented as of 2020-02-23, but planned for 2020 .https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r831c41a3f9b353cfc187dc2092515fe707d4ebf13cbb727524f1c600%40%3Cdev.arrow.apache.org%3E https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1644?src=confmacro

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the right answer, but it can helps.

We could try to convert your dictionary to a pandas DataFrame, and after this write this to `.parquet` file:

```
import pandas as pd
from fastparquet import write, ParquetFile

d = {
    "product": {
        "id": "abcdef",
        "price": 19.99,
        "specs": {
            "voltage": "110v",
            "color": "white"
        }
    },
    "user": "Daniel Severo"
}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(d)
write('file_test.parquet', df_test)
```

This would raise and error:

```
ValueError: Can't infer object conversion type: 0                                   abcdef
1                                    19.99
2    {'voltage': '110v', 'color': 'white'}
Name: product, dtype: object
```

So a easy solution is to convert the `product` column to lists:

```
df_test['product'] = df_test['product'].apply(lambda x: [x])

# this should now works
write('file_test.parquet', df_test)

# and now compare the file with the initial DataFrame
ParquetFile('file_test.parquet').to_pandas().explode('product')
    index            product                                 user
0   id               abcdef                             Daniel Severo
1   price             19.99                             Daniel Severo
2   specs   {'voltage': '110v', 'color': 'white'}       Daniel Severo
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this feature has finally been added in arrow/pyarrow 2.0.0:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1644

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/json.html